How to convert the angular momentum operator Lz to an rotational qudit gate for QAOA?
Overall I want to implement QAOA for QuDits and use the angular momentum operator $L_Z$ as the problem Hamiltonian.
For the QuBit QAOA I would e.g. take the Pauli-$Z$ operator as the problem Hamiltonian and convert it to a rotational gate by taking $e^{-i\frac{\theta}{2}Z}$.
How would I do this for QuDits using $L_Z$ as the problem Hamiltonian with e.g. $d=5$?
